# Is it possible to apply "Select Distinct" to any column of the query that isn’t in the first place?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, like the query below:

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        song_name,
        year_rank AS rank,
        group_name
    FROM 
        billboard_top_100_year_end
    WHERE 
        year = 2010
    ORDER BY 
        rank
    LIMIT 10
)
SELECT
    rank,
    group_name,
    song_name
FROM 
    T1
LIMIT 10
```

I need to put the column `song_name` on the top because I didn’t know how to use DISTINCT if the column `song_name` was in third place.

So, after I needed to query again just to obtain the exactly same result but by another order of visualization.

Comment: Postgres or SQL Server?  Please tag correctly.  They are not the same.  But in general, DISTINCT applies to all columns in the query.

Comment: DISTINCT applies to all the selected columns that are not aggregated. Perhaps your goal is "first in group" for sql server - a term you can use for searching if that is the case.

Comment: It's on PostgreSQL, it's correctly now, thank you.
So, by what you're saying, by my query the DISTINCT was applied in all columns, right?
But if i'd like to apply then in just one column, some column that wasn't in the first place.
Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  DISTINCT just doesn't work that way but if you show what you're trying to get we might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm coding to solve the problem of this exercise: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/9650-find-the-top-10-ranked-songs-in-2010?python=

I know, that therer are another ways to get it, but i'd like to discovery how to use the Distinct like I said.

I already have the correctly aswer, but it's just to know.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a *keyword*, not a *function* - it applies to the whole result set (therefore every column), ensuring there are no duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` does not apply to a certain column of the result set, but to all. It just eliminates duplicate result rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM tab;
```

is the same as

```
SELECT a, b, c, FROM tab GROUP BY a, b, c;
```

Perhaps you are looking for the (non-standard!) PostgreSQL extension `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (song_name)
       song_name, col2, col2, ...
FROM tab
ORDER BY song_name, col2;
```

With the `ORDER BY`, this will give you for each `song_name` the result with the smallest `col2`. If you omit the `ORDER BY`, you will get a random result row for each `song_name`.